# Fetching related record data and updating them using LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

My objective is to build a LWC component which will display the list of related opportunity records based on account and also enable users to update the stage and amount fields. I am getting the child records displayed correctly, but am encountering a few errors:

1. whenever I type anything in the fields, I get a popup message- *This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 736493086)*
2. The update operation is not occuring for some reason.
3. I also need help in the stage picklist field, it is currently getting displayed in the form of text, but I need the picklist values to appear.

Thanks

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>

        <template for:each={opportunities} for:item="opp">
            <tr key={opp.Id}>
                <td><lightning-input label="Opp Name" type="text" value={opp.Name} onchange={handleInputChange} data-field="Name" ></lightning-input></td>
                <td><lightning-input label="Opp Stage Name" type="text" value={opp.StageName} onchange={handleInputChange} data-field="StageName" ></lightning-input></td>
                <td><lightning-input label="Opp Amount" type="number" value={opp.Amount} onchange={handleInputChange} data-field="Amount" ></lightning-input></td>
                <td>
                    <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleSave} data-id={opp.Id}></lightning-button>
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
      
    

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement,api, wire, track } from 'lwc';

import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import displayRelatedOpp_Account from '@salesforce/apex/relatedOpp_Account.displayRelatedOpp_Account';
import updateOppDetails_Test3 from '@salesforce/apex/relatedOpp_Account.updateOppDetails_Test3';
//import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';



import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
import STAGENAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';
import AMOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Amount';

export default class DisplayRelatedOpp_Test3 extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    columns;
    draftValues = [];
    @api opportunities =[];

   

    @wire(displayRelatedOpp_Account, { accId: '$recordId' })
    opps(result)
    {
        
        if (result.error)
        {
            this.opportunities = undefined;
        }
        else if (result.data)
        {
            this.opportunities = result.data;
        }
    }

    handleInputChange(event)
    {
        if(event.target.label=='Opp Name')
        {
            opportunities.name=event.target.value;
        }
        else if (event.target.label=='Opp Stage Name')
        {
            opportunities.stagename=event.target.value;
        }
        else if (event.target.label=='Opp Amount')
        {
            opportunities.amount=event.target.value;
        }
    }

  

    handleSave(event)
    {
        updateOppDetails_Test3({accountId: this.recordId, oppName: this.opportunities.name, oppStage: this.opportunities.stagename, oppAmount: this.opportunities.amount})
        .then(oppDetail => {console.log(JSON.stringify(oppDetail))})
        .catch(error=>(console.log(error)))

        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Opportunity updated',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
    }

}
```

APex:

```
public with sharing class relatedOpp_Account {


    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> displayRelatedOpp_Account(string accId) {

        List<opportunity> oppList = [select id, name, stagename, amount, accountId from opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];

        if (!oppList.isEmpty())
        {
            return oppList;
        }
        return null;

    }


    @AuraEnabled

    public static String updateOppDetails_Test3(String accountId, string oppName, string oppStage, integer oppAmount )

    {
           // system.debug(OppData);
           // return 'done';

        list<opportunity> updatedOppList = new list<opportunity>();

        if(accountId!=null)
        {
            Opportunity opp = new opportunity();
            opp.accountId = accountId;
            opp.name = oppName;
            opp.stagename = oppStage;
            opp.amount = oppAmount;
            updatedOppList.add(opp);
        }
       

        if(!updatedOppList.isempty())
        {
            update updatedOppList;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@api opportunities =[];
```

Makes the field read-only. Remove the `@api`.

---

```
this.opportunities = result.data;
```

Wire data is always read-only. Clone it first:

```
this.opportunities = result.data.map((record)=>({...record}));
```

---

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Opportunity> displayRelatedOpp_Account(string accId) {

    List<opportunity> oppList = [select id, name, stagename, amount, accountId from opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];

    if (!oppList.isEmpty())
    {
        return oppList;
    }
    return null;

}
```

Don't return null values, it just makes it more likely to crash your code.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Opportunity> displayRelatedOpp_Account(string accId) {
    return [select id, name, stagename, amount, accountId from opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
}
```

---

```
opportunities.name=event.target.value;
```

`opportunities` is an array. You need to find the right element in that array.

```
<lightning-input data-id={opp.Id} ...>
```

...

```
const opp = this.opportunities.find((record)=>record.Id === event.target.dataset.id);
```

---

You can use the name attribute in HTML to reduce your code complexity to just:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
  const opp = this.opportunities.find((opp)=>opp.id === event.target.dataset.id);
  opp[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
}
```

With your template having:

```
<lightning-input name="Name" ...
<lightning-input name="StageName" ...
<lightning-input name="Amount" ...
```

---

`handleSave` has the same problem; you're assuming it's not an Array.

First, change your Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled public static void updateOppDetails_Test3(Opportunity[] records) {
  update records;
}
```

Then, change your JavaScript to match:

```
handleSave(event) {
    updateOppDetails_Test3({ records: this.opportunities })
        .then(oppDetail => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(oppDetail));
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Opportunity updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
        })
        .catch(error => (console.log(error)))
}
```

Notice how we put the toast message inside the then block. We don't want to display success before it actually saves successfully.

---

> I also need help in the stage picklist field, it is currently getting displayed in the form of text, but I need the picklist values to appear.

Because you used `lightning-input`. If you want a picklist field, you need to use the appropriate type of element, such as `lightning-select` or `lightning-combobox`. You'll also need `getPicklistValues` to load the picklist values, and possibly `getObjectInfo` as well.

---

There's still some cleanup to do here, but this should be enough to fix the first round of problems in your code.